# php - count and echo the number of non empty folders/directories

Tags: php, count, directory

I want to search search through several directories/folders and count and echo the number of ones that have non-empty subfolders/subdirectories.
I know how to count the number of files for a single subdirectory by the below. However, I could not find any help on counting the global number of directories that have files.

```
  $dir = '../location/' . $nameofadirectory .'/subDir/';
  $count = count(glob($dir . "*"));
  echo $count;
```

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php use a loop for mutiple scan

Comment: that looks like something that would list the files found in the folders. I am not interested in doing that.